# Default selected options in SelectMultiple widget

Tags: django, django-1.8

I am passing several `forms.SelectMultiple` widgets to a view as a shortcut to render them. Is there any way to pass which options need to be checked by default? The source code doesn't seem to allow that:

```
class SelectMultiple(Select):
    allow_multiple_selected = True

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        if value is None:
            value = []
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        output = [format_html('<select multiple="multiple"{}>', flatatt(final_attrs))]
        options = self.render_options(choices, value)
        if options:
            output.append(options)
        output.append('</select>')
        return mark_safe('\n'.join(output))

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        if isinstance(data, (MultiValueDict, MergeDict)):
            return data.getlist(name)
        return data.get(name, None)
```

Again, let me repeat I am only using the widget. It is not bound to any form field, so I can't use `initial`.

Comment: You are still using Django-1.8?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem not up to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of selected elements is in the `value`. So you can make a widget with:

```
CHOICES = [
    ('1', 'red'),
    ('2', 'green'),
    ('3', 'blue'),
]

widget=forms.SelectMultiple()
widget.render('item-name', value=['1', '3'], choices=CHOICES)
```

In the source code we see that the [`render_options` is implemented as [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/forms/widgets.py#L535-L547):

> ```
>     def render_options(self, choices, selected_choices):
>         # Normalize to strings.
>         selected_choices = set(force_text(v) for v in selected_choices)
>         output = []
>         for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
>             if isinstance(option_label, (list, tuple)):
>                 output.append(format_html('<optgroup label="{}">', force_text(option_value)))
>                 for option in option_label:
>                     output.append(self.render_option(selected_choices, *option))
>                 output.append('</optgroup>')
>             else:
>                 output.append(self.render_option(selected_choices, option_value, option_label))
>         return '\n'.join(output)
> ```

and in the [**`render_option`** method [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/forms/widgets.py#L519-L533):

> ```
>     def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):
>         if option_value is None:
>             option_value = ''
>         option_value = force_text(option_value)
>         if option_value in selected_choices:
>             selected_html = mark_safe(' selected="selected"')
>             if not self.allow_multiple_selected:
>                 # Only allow for a single selection.
>                 selected_choices.remove(option_value)
>         else:
>             selected_html = ''
>         return format_html('<option value="{}"{}>{}</option>',
>                            option_value,
>                            selected_html,
>                            force_text(option_label))
> ```

so it checks if the value is in the list of values you passed.

Comment: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'value'`

Comment: @dabadaba: sorry, it should of course be passed to the `render` method.